# What is an operation group?

Tags: operation

In general what makes two or more operations part of an operation group?

And as an example, why are these operations all in the same operation group?
https://tzkt.io/ooyynpmcUE1wPUWatxZxqk3Nnwao7NxteZZfnPW2YRkEWeQMQyj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call those batch operations.

When you create a manager operation, it can contain multiple sub-operations of the following kinds (transaction, origination, delegation, reveal). The limits of that operation are defined by gas and storage limits.

**Why is that useful?**

- You can inject more operations per second;
- It is cheaper;

Comment: ah okay, thanks! And my understanding is if a contract creates a transfer, both of those (the original contract call, and contract-initiated transfer) are also part of the same operation group. Are there other ways operations 
can be part of the same operation group?

Comment: contract-initiated (transfers, originations, and delegations) are internal calls of sub-operations, and you can consider them as sub-sub-operations.

Comment: An operation group is a list of operations that are all signed by the same implicit account. The main points of these groups are that:

Comment: - atomicity: either all the operations in the batch succeed or none is applied
- efficiency: the whole batch is signed only once so it is much more efficient to check, hence it requires much less gas
- usability: the whole batch only increments the counter of the implicit account signing it by one; for this reason it is easier for tools to provide sending several operations per blocks using operation batches than tracking counter changes.